# what does the keyword this does in the code and are there any alternate methods without this keyword?

Tags: java, this

in the class Student here what does the keyword this used in the functions refer to?
what does it return exactly?
is it only used in java or c/c++ also?
is there any difference if used in any other language?

```
class Student
{
private String name;
private String section;
public static Comparator BY_NAME = new ByName();
public static Comparator BY_SECTION = new BySection();

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setSection(String section) {
    this.section = section;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public String getSection()
{
    return this.section;
}

private static class ByName implements Comparator
{
    public int compare(Object s1, Object s2)
    {
        return ((Student)s1).name.compareTo(((Student)s2).name);
    }
}

private static class BySection implements Comparator
{
    public int compare(Object s1, Object s2)
    {
        return ((Student)s1).section.compareTo(((Student)s2).section);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java and c++ "this" is referring to the object's variable and NOT the class's variable.